# Any AS3 library needs to be compiled with standard mode instead of strict mode?

Tags: actionscript-3, functional-programming

I see a lot of AS3 libraries are written in strict mode compile fashion. They are all very Java like. I haven't seen any libraries that requires compilation in normal mode. More functional programming like, and probably use a lot of prototype and scoping magic, since ActionScript 3 can be very much JavaScript like if used normal mode compilation.

In many cases, functional style programming can be more powerful IF used correctly, and thus produce more elegant code.

My question is that is there any library in AS3 that dares to for go the bondage of strict mode, and uses normal mode?

Comment: Can you provide a code example of something that you would like to do to make your code more functional, powerful and elegant that would not pass strict mode?

Comment: Well, plenty of libraries use Object and * casting back and forth, but still they're pretty stiff. What I'm guessing you mean is are there any as3 libraries use less code/simple code ? like as2 used too ? Well, my opinion is that people are trying to move away from that. Still, as3 has a long way to go in that direction, but people seem determined to take that root, maybe because of all the nasty stuff as2 was asociated with( scoping issues, silent failures, etc. ). For developers that's ok, but for designer and new commers that ain't rockin. there should be a simpler interface for them.

Comment: The tendency is towared larger apps( flex and other frameworks ), larger speeds ( see PixelBender, Alchemy, etc. )...It doesn't look like it's going to get simpler. Maybe when html5 and stuff like that will kick in good, things will consider things twice. Have a look at HaXe though...it has some pretty solid stuff that not even as3 has, like enums and what not, but still, if you know javascript/ecmascript it's pretty easy to pickup, not to mention it compiles to JS, PHP, C++.

Comment: I felt strange that why AS3 is pretend to be Java, instead of following its roots as prototype based dynamic language. I guess your comment answers the question! For designers that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that writing code only to compile in normal mode it's actually easy. If anyone should choose this, it might be because of lack of time, but will only (eventually) lead to "rushed" code.
The actual DARE is to write proper, robust, strict AS3 code.